# Automatically create jobs in Dagster

Tags: jobs, dagster

I'm new to Dagster and I'm getting beat up too much to get my scenario to work.

I would like to create jobs dynamically, and I've been to the Dagster documentation but I couldn't reproduce it at all.

My scenario is as follows:

I have 3 functions in python (@op), the first being where I fetch data from an EP. In the second function I process this data, and in the third function I receive a name of "client" as a parameter and with the processed result of the second function, I save it in that client's database. Example:

```
@op
def step1():
    return {"a" : 1, "b:" 2, "c: 3"}

@op
def step2(result):
     //process exemple
    return {"a" : 4, "b" : 5, "c" : 6}

@op
def step3(result,client):
  //update in database client


@graph
def process():
    response = step1()
    result_process = step2(response)
    step3(result_process, "name_client")

@job
def job_examplo():
   process()
```

the problem is that I have a list of customers, and I didn't want to create multiple @op by passing a different customer name. I tried to do something like:

```
clients = [
    "example_microsoft",
    "example_apple",
    "example_amazon",
    ...
    ...
    "examplo_skynet"

]

@graph
def process():
    response = step1()
    result_process = step2(response)
    
    for client_name in clients:
         step3(result_process, "client_name")
```

But when I do this approach, I get an error. Is there any way at this stage I can generate this step 3 dynamically?

Additional Information: I am using DockerRunLauncher

I already tried to use the outputs, but without success. https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/ops-jobs-graphs/dynamic-graphs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you don't really need to create jobs dynamically, more that you just need to be able to configure the job with a list of clients (see the [configuration](https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/configuration/config-schema#run-configuration) docs) Maybe something like

```py
@op
def step1():
    return {"a" : 1, "b:" 2, "c: 3"}

@op
def step2(result):
    # process exemple
    return {"a" : 4, "b" : 5, "c" : 6}

@op(config_schema={"client_list": Field([str])})
def step3(context, result,client):
    # update in database client
    client_list = context.op_config["client_list"]
    # loop over client list and do the database update

@graph
def process():
    response = step1()
    result_process = step2(response)
    step3(result_process)

@job
def job_examplo():
   process()
```

Then you can do the looping in your op. If you want to parallelize the `step3` op across all your clients, you could use [dynamic graphs](https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/ops-jobs-graphs/dynamic-graphs), which might looks something like this:

```py
@op
def step1():
    return {"a" : 1, "b:" 2, "c: 3"}

@op
def step2(result):
    # process exemple
    return {"a" : 4, "b" : 5, "c" : 6}

@op(config_schema={"client_list": Field([str])},
    out={"result": DynamicOut(str))
def parallelize_clients(context):
    client_list = context.op_config["client_list"]
    for i, c in client_list:
        yield DynamicOutput(c, mapping_key=str(i))

@op
def step3(result,client):
    # update in database client
    pass

@graph
def process():
    response = step1()
    result_process = step2(response)
    clients = parallelize_clients()
    clients.map(lambda client: step3(result_process, client))

job_examplo = process.to_job()

# To execute

job_examplo.execute_in_process(run_config={"ops": {"parallelize_clients": {"config": {"client_list": ["client1", "client2", "client3"]}}}}
```

There are a couple ways to execute this code, see the [dagster job execution docs](https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/ops-jobs-graphs/job-execution) for more details.

To summarize the methods in brief, you can do any of the following:

This method launches the [Dagit UI](https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/ops-jobs-graphs/job-execution#dagit) in a web browser, where you can select your job and provide configuration via the Launchpad

```
# from the command line
dagit -f file_with_jobs.py
```

This method launches the job directly via the [Dagster CLI](https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/ops-jobs-graphs/job-execution#dagster-cli):

```bash
dagster job execute -f file_with_jobs.py --job job_examplo --config path/to/run_config.yaml
```

In this method your configuration must be saved in a yaml file. Configuration for the example job would be something like

```yaml
ops:
  parallelize_clients:
    config:
      client_list:
        - client1
        - client2
```

You can also launch jobs programmatically using the [Python API](https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/ops-jobs-graphs/job-execution#python-apis), which can be helpful for debugging or unit testing (Note that this method will launch your job in a single process, so you won't get any parallelism):

```py
from file_with_jobs import job_examplo

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = job_examplo.execute_in_process(config={"ops": {"parallelize_clients": {"config": {"client_list": ["client1", "client2"]}}}}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, I'm new to both Dagster and Python. Until 20 days ago I only programmed in PHP. I tried to apply your proposed code in parallel, but I'm having a hard time knowing where I would pass the customer list, as I've tried in a few places and haven't been able to. print of my code : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fwv-CkHA3Zx6G6PTKVcRTCtqnOeVfTsX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: no worries at all, it's a lot to jump to a new language, especially with a relatively involved framework like Dagster. I added some details around how to execute jobs with configuration, I hope that provides some clarity and can help you get unstuck. Happy to provide more help if needed.

Comment: Dude, really, thank you so much, you helped me a lot. I managed to solve my problem and the solution is already working. Once again, thank you very much